# Azure F-Series VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

What are those F-Size VMs that are listed in pricing and listed as an option to deploy? I am unable to find any information on them.
[F Instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N82WU.jpg)

Comment: I thought the F series were free, but since they have pricing information, I guess not...

Answer (score 2):

The F-Series is intended for processor intensive workloads.

Taken from The [Azure Virtual Machine Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/)

> The F-Series virtual machines sport 2GB RAM and 16 GB of local solid state drive (SSD) per CPU core, and are optimized for compute intensive workloads. The F-series is based on the 2.4 GHz Intel Xeon® E5-2673 v3 (Haswell) processor, which can achieve clock speeds as high as 3.1 GHz with the Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0. These VMs are suitable for scenarios like batch processing, web servers, analytics and gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft [recently announced](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/f-series-vm-size/) these VM sizes. Per the announcement, they may be a better value than the Dv2 series if your workload is CPU bound. Note that the CPUs for both Dv2-Series and F-Series are the same - `2.4 GHz Intel Xeon E5-2673 v3 (Haswell)`.

> This is the same CPU performance as the Dv2-Series of VMs with 2GB of
>   memory per CPU core at a lower per-hour price.
>
> The F-Series VMs are an excellent choice for gaming servers, web
>   servers and batch processing. Any workload which does not need as much
>   memory or local SSD per CPU core will benefit from the value of the
>   F-Series. The F-Series sizes range from one to 16 CPU cores with
>   options for both standard and premium storage optimized sizes.

Answer (score 1):

They are already listed in the [showcase](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/). Basically they are CPU-wise equivalent to Dv2 of the same size but have about two times less memory and about three times less disk space available to the user and they are about 20 percent cheaper. The intent is that if your application uses a lot of processor core time but doesn't benefit from large amount of memory and disk space you can save about 20 percent cash by moving to F-series.